# c++ function template restrict parameter type

Tags: c++, c++17

Given the class

```
class foo {  
  public:  
    void func(std::string s){};  
    void func(int i){};  
    void func2(std::string s){};  
    void func2(int i){};  
 };
```

I'd like to get rid of the multiple function overloads by just using template functions. However, the functions should ONLY accept an int or a std::string.

I see how this can be accomplished using concepts in c++20. However, I do not have access to a compiler with concepts support.

What would be a way to accomplish such a goal in c++17? Id like to be able to accomplish in the template specification using some form of std::enable_if or similiar, as opposed to using static_assert.

The answer below shows this can be done. Would there be a way to only have to define the 'template' definition once?

````
    class foo {  
      template <typename arg_t,   
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<arg_t>, int> || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<arg_t>, std::string>, boo> = true>  
      void func(arg_t arg){}  
      template <typename arg_t,   
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<arg_t>, int> || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<arg_t>, std::string>, boo> = true>  
      void func2(arg_t arg){}
    };
    ```
````

Comment: I'm curious why you want to only allow those two types. If you only provide one function template that unifies both current overloads, surely it must be very generic to support both `int` and `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `enable_if` you could write the function like

```
template <typename arg_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<arg_t>, int> ||
                                           std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<arg_t>, std::string>,
                                           bool> = true>
void func(arg_t arg){}
```

Comment: should probably use `arg_t&&`

Comment: @Apples The OP was using pass by value so I kept it with that.

Comment: @NathanOliver In OP's example we have total 4 member function but in your example we'll only two member functions: one taking an `int` or other taking `std::string`. I thought that OP wanted to have the same effect as having four member functions two of which will take a single `int` and other two `std::string`.

Comment: This answer is wonderful. Ideally, I'd like to able to apply a template like this to ALL the functions, without having to repeat it. Would that be possible?

Comment: @user3472 Not really, that was one of the things concepts helped to fix. You could use a macro to get rid of most of the repetition or you could make a custom type trait to bring the boiler plate down to `template <typename arg_t, std::enable_if_t<my_trait_v<arg_t>, bool> = true>`

Comment: @Anya My reading of the Q is the the OP wants 2 functions, each of which can take either an `int` or a `string` as the parameter type.